# Can you find O in this math riddle?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

If:

> R = 1,111
>   T = 2,222
>   E = 3,333
>   N = 4,444

What is O equal to?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is

> 8,888

Explanation follows

R = 1,111

> 1+1+1+1 = FOU(R)

T = 2,222

> 2+2+2+2 = EIGH(T)

E = 3,333

> 3+3+3+3 = TWELV(E)

N = 4,444

> 4+4+4+4 = SIXTEE(N)

O =

> 8,888
> 8+8+8+8 = THIRTY TW(O)

Comment: In which case the commas used in the question are deliberately misleading

Comment: Just for the heck of it, then , D,DDD is also a solution :-)

Comment: The commas are in fact misleading.

Comment: May be, the commas are just thousand separators.

Comment: How do you know it has to be 32? Couldn't it be any number ending with two? Or is there a number sequence? But then 4,8,12,16,32 doesn't make any sence. So I am assuming it is because all the single digits have to sum up to a number ending with two, right?

Comment: Because 1. it should be four digits. 2. All digits should be same 3. the some of digits should end up with 'O'. 8,888 is the only four digit number that satisfy all these three criteria